# Display multiple glyphicon's in gridview column based on flags

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, glyphicons

I have a gridview with bounded fields.  In the first column "Priority" I'd like to bind the priority number but also add multiple glyphicon's based on flags from other columns in the datatable. There are columns "HOT_FLAG", "WATCH_FLAG" and "INFO_FLAG" and if those are true, I need to display the corresponding glyphicon.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="dgv_Test" 
        GridLines="None"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowCreated="dgv_RowCreated"
        EnableHeadervisualstyles ="true"
        runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PRIORITY" HeaderText="#"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COL2" HeaderText="COL2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COL3" HeaderText="COL3" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I'm assuming I need to convert these bound fields to template fields (or something else) and set the Glyphicon's in the code behind but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="HotFlag" runat="server" ImageUrl="path/to/image" Visible='<%# Eval("HOT_FLAG") %>'/>
        <asp:Image ID="WatchFlag" runat="server" ImageUrl="path/to/image" Visible='<%# Eval("WATCH_FLAG") %>'/>
        <asp:Image ID="InfoFlag" runat="server" ImageUrl="path/to/image" Visible='<%# Eval("INFO_FLAG") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: This worked great.  Ideally I'd like to use glyphicons but I think I can add a span and set the visible to the same thing.  I'll try that next